# count how many time an item has been used, and reset that number

Tags: sql, sql-server

need some help please...
my problem is, there are some items lets say a1,a2,a,3 - b1,b2,b3 - c1,c2,c3 which after certain uses (4) need to be cleansed to be used again.
i want to keep some data about this process so i made the following table in SQL

```
CREATE table items
(
  itemName varchar(10),
  concept varchar(10)
)
```

itemName is self explanatory: a1,a2,a3 etc.
concept is either "Use" or lets say.. "Cleanse"

data example

```
INSERT INTO items (itemName, concept) 
values 
    ('a1','Use'),
    ('a2','Use'),
    ('c1','Use'),
    ('b3','Use'),
    ('c2','Use'),
    ('a1','Use'),
    ('a1','Use'),
    ('a1','Use'),
    ('c2','Use'),
    ('a1','Cleanse')
```

```
select COUNT(*) as count,itemname, concept from items group by concept, itemName
```

[image]

so every 4 insert of item "a1" with concept "Use" the next one has to be "Cleanse"
for now, i have been able to keep track of the process but, i've noticed some items being used more or less times than 4.

now, the problem is... i have no idea how make a counter limited to 4 and how to reset it after..
perhaps, it needs a table for only Use and another for Cleanse ??.
i though with a simple count(*) would be enough... i was so wrong.

perhaps i need a validation somewhere else ._. ugh im lost

oh and btw im using tkinter gui to enter this data

so.. please some enlightenment

i imagined with a count(*) query would work

Comment: SQL has no inherent order. There must be a way to order the rows, a timestamp or something, so you can know if `('a1', 'use')` comes before or after `('a1', 'cleanse')`. And what database are you using, please?

Comment: Hello, im using SQL server 10.0.1600.22.
oke then im adding a datetime column with default current_timestamp

Comment: Why not add a line `a1,use1` each time you use, which will be completed with current time stamp, the same `a1,clean` when you wash it. You then write a view to query the number of uses after the last clean and use a case statement to show "for use" or "to clean"

Comment: Time to upgrade your sql server. You are seriously still using sql server 2008r2 without even any service packs? The latest version of 2008r2 has been unsupported for several years now.